# why is Grub not loading after Installing 11.10 Beta2 after windows 7?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, grub2

I'm on a new machine, single sata drive.

Installed Windows 7.

Installed 11.10 beta 2, twice:

- First with a separate home partition. Grub didn't load and boot was right to win7
- Second I blew away the new Linux partitions and installed 'along windows' all defaults. Result was same as above.

I attempted this: [No Grub after installing Ubuntu beside Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24479/no-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-10-10-beside-windows-7-straight-to-windows/24486#24486)

And now on boot I get: "error file not loaded," followed by the grub rescue prompt. No grub. No Windows 7.

This has always worked in the past. Windows 7 first, then Ubuntu. Is this a problem with the 11.10 beta?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to AskUbuntu - well done for finding the resolution.  Please add an answer for your solution - you will also be able to accept the answer in a few hours after posting.  Without an answer - the question will appear to be unresolved by the "system".  Thanks.

Comment: Still does not appear to allow me to answer my own question. I assume it is a rep. restraint.

Comment: You need to post an answer in the answers section.  If for whatever reason, the system doesnt allow you to, click the flag link and let the moderators know that there is something wrong with your account.

Comment: Seems I needed to re-authenticate then I could see the answer button. May be a bug, I'm not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this (rather then the answer to the similar question above) appears to have solved the problem.

Stuck in grub rescue after Windows install

The first wasn't as clear about which partition grub should be installed on (confusing it with which should be mounted).

By comparing both answers I've found mine. Cheers.

Edit:

the 'this' after 'Following this' was a link to the other question. Seems I lost the hyperlink in an edit. Unfortunately I can't remember all the details of how I solved this

Comment: Care to go in to a little more detail?

Comment: the 'this' after 'Following this' was a link to the other question.  Seems I lost the hyperlink in an edit. Unfortunately I can't remember all the details of how I solved this.