# Dual boot problem! (GRUB PROBLEM)

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I had just finished my setup for dual boot, everything went fine but I lost my ubuntu:

- zero fill + create 2 Windows partitions (FINE)
- Install Windows and configure C:/ for The system and D:/ For documents (FINE)
- Create 2 partitions for Ubuntu, one for the "/" and other for SWAP (FINE)
- Reinstall windows on the C: test, if I ever need to do that, FAILED, now I just have Windows on the boot, I lost that option to launch either windows or ubuntu.

How do I fix that?

EDIT: Just googled a bit and some people say it's a grub problem

Please help me =/

Comment: I'm confused did you have Ubuntu installed first then Installed Windows or Windows first then Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah, fisrt installed Windows, then Ubuntu, then re-installed WIndows Just to make sure if I ever needed to do that I`d be ok, but now Windows loads directly, no menu from ubuntu

Comment: Please see possible duplicate questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows, http://askubuntu.com/questions/24479/no-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-beside-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

By reinstalling Windows *after* Ubuntu you have overwritten the Grub file that loads Ubuntu.

The easiest way to fix your Grub file is with **Boot Repair** you can get more info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

The instructions are:

1. Boot your LiveCD/LiveUSB of Ubuntu
2. type in a terminal `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
3. On the Boot Repair window select **Recommended Repair**
4. If repair is successful reboot your computer and you should then be able to use your Grub file

I have given the quick method for using boot repair to fix Grub, you may want to read the Ubuntu Wiki I linked to for more detailed info.

You had this problem because Windows is not respectful of any other boot files already on the computer and will overwrite the MBR with it's own files.  Not a total disaster as you can fix it with the above instructions but an annoyance brought to you by Microsoft none the less.

Comment: Hell you just saved my life! *-*

I love you <3