# How to install GRUB on the hard-disk?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows, live-usb

I'm kinda new to Linux. I wanted to install Ubuntu, so **I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7**, (I partitioned my HDD and left it unallocated) Ubuntu did not ask where to install and stuff, it just installed.

So I rebooted the PC, to boot Ubuntu, but there was no GRUB, it booted straight to Windows 7. So I found this question: [No Grub after installing Ubuntu beside Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24479/no-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-beside-windows-7)

So I wanted to try what it said in the answer of that question, so I inserted my LiveUSB, and booted from it, and the **GRUB APPEARED!** I don't know why when I boot from that USB, GRUB appears. So I booted Ubuntu and it works. *But I see the GRUB only when the USB flash drive is connected.* So it looks like the GRUB installed in the USB.

My question is, how can I *transfer* GRUB to my default partition, so I can get GRUB *without having to boot from the LiveUSB*.

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel so, you have to **read** (not only see) all the steps of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/62483). Be carefully with all the commands that you'll enter; *specially note the 3º step*, there you will/have mount the partition of your HDD, there is where you (IMHO) were wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be possible GRUB is not properly install in your pc or is booting from directly USB.

ubuntu also can be install inside in windows if you are not selected any partitions or may be another drive. now you can use easyBCD software that is very good tool for booting and you do not need USB for booting.

Dowload Easybcd software it is free for home user install it open it you will see add new entry click on it go to linux tab add entry click on select "GRUB2" edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting

Download here:http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

for more use watch youtube videos of easyBCD.

Comment: Thanks, I want to try using EasyBCD, the problem is, I don't know whattimeout should I use, and things like that... But thanks anyway!