# Ubuntu 14.04 only boots with USB stick

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

My Ubuntu screen turns black after boot up, unless I insert the "live" USB in the PC before booting up.  I have tried different distros, USB sticks and computers and they all have the same issue.

Do I need to change Grub files?  How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You probably install grub to the USB stick instead of the HDD.

Comment: You didn't give me feedback. Did it work for you?

Comment: I discovered ubuntu 16 wqs just released so i agve that a whir and that worked

Answer (score 3):

Your grub is surely not installed in your Hard drive but your booting device... Install grub on your Hard Disk Drive and observe again.

Comment: How would i go and do that?

Comment: Please check this. It will probably help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/259897/how-to-install-grub-on-the-hard-disk