# Dual-boot problem with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have **Windows 7** (32 bit) which is already installed on my desktop. Now I'm trying to install **Ubuntu 14.04.1** on the same system. But it isn't creating the boot loader after installing successfully. And by default, is opening Windows.

If there is a Grub file problem, then what should I do? 
How can I update it?

(I didn't format the disk where Ubuntu is installed.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your PC have ubuntu installed but it is not showing to you on booting.

You can try these things first.

1.When you are starting PC, press key (like `esc` and `f12`) to reach `boot menu`, maybe there you can see option to select i.e `1.UBUNTU 2.HDD 3.WINDOWS` etc. and from there you can go into UBUNTU.

2.Check from Windows that the `disk` on which you just installed UBUNTU have format of `ext3` or `ext4` and some of it's space (may be 8GB) is filled. If yes then you have `UBUNTU` installed and you may try to install `grub` via l`ive usb`.

Comment: 1. Windows and Ubuntu are probably installed on the same physical drive, so BIOS boot menu won’t help. 2. Windows cannot recognize any of `ext` filesystem series.

Comment: @ Akhilesh kumar i agree with #Melebius. would u plz explain it?

Comment: @sushant [this may help you](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24479/no-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-beside-windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Grub is not installed in the correct location.

Boot Ubuntu from your installation-media (USB-stick,DVD)

Open the terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T`

The run this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Click the `Recommended repair`-button and follow on-screen instructions.

Boot-repair will provide an URL for the boot-info-summary, please note down that URL.
After the repair is done you should be able to boot to Grub-menu where you can choose to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

If you still can't boot to Grub, please post URL to your boot-info-summary.

Comment: Dear @mook765 do you want to say that i should boot ubuntu by usb/dvd then use terminal? Would you plz explain how will i work on ubuntu terminal if i don't have way to select OS between windows &ubuntu. How will i open terminal?

Comment: Boot from your installation-media which you used to install Ubuntu. Choose `Try Ubuntu without installing`.  After Ubuntu has loaded press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open terminal. then enter the mentioned commands, one after the other.

Comment: Should i connected with internet at that time? Bcz i tried it without connection it's displaying lots pf errors (url)like file not found etc

Comment: Yes, you need to be connected to the Internet, wired connection is preferable.