# How do I switch between Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu on a Windows 10 PC, but how do I switch between them? When I start the computer it just starts in Windows automatically as if nothing has happened. I haven't seen any boot menu saying Ubuntu after installing and rebooting.

Comment: Do you see a boot menu with Windows 10 and Ubuntu when you start the computer or does the computer boot to either Windows 10 or Ubuntu automatically? Which one of the two OSs doesn't boot?

Comment: it just start in windows as if nothing has happend

Comment: i haven't seen anything saying Ubuntu after installing and rebooting

Comment: you need to go into your UEFI system setup and change the boot priority to the location where your linux OS is installed.

Comment: UEFI setup.??? there is only the windows boot in the bios

Comment: @Mads When you start your laptop/PC immediately, you need to press F10 or F2(depending on the manufaturer) to see this Setup.

Comment: Yes and IT stands on uefi

Comment: @Mads Have you tried changing to legacy?

Comment: I'm about to go APEshit on my laptop and rip off the lid.

Comment: Now Ive changed to legacy and now IT says there is No bootable device

Comment: so now i have changed to UEFI again.

Comment: No help ???????

Comment: while installing Ubuntu did you say Install alongside Windows10? If you did that and did a reboot atr the end, it should usually show you the GRUB menu instead of booting to windows directly. If nothing works you insert a LIVE Ubuntu DVD and follow the instructions here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/24479/no-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-beside-windows-7

Comment: it never asked me that. sort of crap that it doesnt work. seriously crap!!! i even have installed the 16.?? now and it still doesnt work, piece of shit

Comment: sorry for the language but i've used 4+ hours on this shit now. amazing we are in 2017 and its still a problem making something that just works!

Comment: try `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda`

Comment: Press `F12` or `F8` to open Boot Menu. There you should find Ubuntu listed

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer because there are already 14 comments.
First, uefi is the new "bios" - see https://www.howtogeek.com/56958/htg-explains-how-uefi-will-replace-the-bios/
At any rate, you need to select which OS to boot from within the uefi or bios menu.

legacy boot will not help as both windows and ubuntu are designed not to boot in legacy mode. You can reinstall or configure ubuntu to boot into legacy mode if you wish, but you can sometimes break windows.

At any rate see [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)
There is a long first answer and at the bottom there is a section troubleshooting

> TROUBLESHOOTING
>
> YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS
>
> This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP

Every bios / uefi interface is different, so we can not tell you exactly how your works. As you boot you may have to hit F9 or F12 to get a "boot menu" which will select which OS to boot. You may have to enter your bios / uefi and select which OS to boot. Look in the location where you selected to boot from the  USB.

For example, one on my laptops, I can only switch between OS by hitting F9 as I boot and selecting an OS. Grub will boot Linux, but not windows, and I can not boot Linux when I select windows. There is no option in the bios to select an OS.

So start going through your bios / uefi menu and try to find the boot menu where you select an OS. You may need to update your bios / uefi . You may need to contact your manufacturer.

You can try to run boot-repair - it will give you a url at the end and post the url here, it will give us a lot of additional information and may give an error messages

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is go to your bios and set ubuntu as default and when you restart, ubuntu has a grub which shows which os is installed and you can choice one among them so that you dont directly boot into windows